# Calculate order of group generated with $a*b$ by knowing order of group generated with $a$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, modules

I have group $F_a$ over multiplicative field module prime $p$ generated by $a$. I know its order: $order(F_a)$
$$
F_a=\left( 1, a\bmod p, a^2\bmod p, a^3\bmod p,\ldots\right)
$$
What will be the best way to calculate order of group $F_{a*b}$, generated by $a*b$?
Currently I have primitive root modulo $p$. I am doing straightforward: multiplying $a*b$, finding discrete logarithm $g^x=a*b\bmod p$, and calculating order by finding $gcd(p-1,x)$. I wonder if there exists quicker way, since logarithm is slow.

Example:
$$
p=17, g=3, a=2
$$
$$
F_2=(1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16), order(F_2)=8
$$
$$
b=2, a*b=4
$$
$$
F_4=(1,4,13,16), order(F_4)=4
$$

Comment: The notation $S_a$ is a bad choice.

Comment: @Shaun what will be better?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe $F_a$?